# How to handle large html text page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a huge(around 20mB) html page which is nothing but pure text. It is a log file for some code running on a server. Now, I am trying to write a chrome plugin which automatically parses this page when someone opens it and adds appropriate links according to my need at certain places.

The page looks like this

```
<html><head></head><body><pre> 20mB of pure text </pre></body></html>
```

So, two questions, second dependent on first, which would help me.
(I am using pure javascript till now. No libraries yet.)

1) How do I parse the page?
2) There is some information in the first 3-4 lines. How do I **easily** get those first few lines and get the data out of it ( if parsing the whole page is not going to be easy)?

Comment: How you parse the page will depend on how the data is structured.

Comment: You need to find a javascript library that would allow you to traverse xml. Then you could easily get the text out of the pre tag.

Comment: As I said, it is 20mB of pure text inside the 'pre' tag. Dump of the log file.

Comment: We need to know the log file's format to help you parse it. Parsing means that you use knowledge of the data structure to convert it into the data contained within it. Is it XML, JSON, or some other format that you are going to explain to us?

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to parse the page for, are you creating a summary?

for Starters, you can get the first 4 lines by adding an id to the pre tag and doing this:

`var first4Lines = document.getElementById("theIdTagOfThePre").innerHTML.split("\n",4);`
if that didnt work right you have to switch the '\n' to a '\r\n'.

Comment: The page is essentially a log file. I will be adding appropriate html links on each line of the 20mb text.